# What is the difference between toPlainString() and toString() in java?

Tags: java, string, bigdecimal

Kindly let me know the difference between this two methods. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried looking at Javadocs?

Answer (score 16):

Java toString() method :

> If you want to represent any object as a string, toString() method
>   comes into existence.The toString() method returns the string
>   representation of the object.

Example :

```
Student s1 = new Student(101,"Raj","lucknow");  
Student s2 = new Student(102,"Vijay","ghaziabad");  

System.out.println(s1);//compiler writes here s1.toString()  
System.out.println(s2);//compiler writes here s2.toString()  

//Output : 101 Raj lucknow
           102 Vijay ghaziabad
```

Java toPlainString() method :

> The java.math.BigDecimal.toPlainString() returns a string
>   representation of this BigDecimal without an exponent field.

Example :

```
MathContext mc = new MathContext(3); // 3 precision
BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal("1234E+4", mc);
// Assign the plain string value of bigDecimal to s
String plainString = bigDecimal.toPlainString();

String str = "Plain string value of " + bigDecimal + " is " + plainString;

// print s value
System.out.println( str );

//Output : Plain string value of 1.23E+7 is 12300000
```

Comment: it might be worth mentioning that every Object has the toString() method since it's defined in the Object class itself!

Comment: Double numDb=1.00000E-28;
BigDecimal b=new BigDecimal(numDb);
String s=b.toString();
System.out.println(s);

The above snippet is working fine for me.  That's why I got in to confusion of the difference between those two methods.